# Problem with adding fxml file to main and using onAction function in fxml

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I've got a problem with adding an fxml file to my JavaFX project. The onAction function in my FXML file doesn't work.
The IntelliJ IDE colored this onAction function red and I can't use it in the controller. Do you know the reason?

Here is code in fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="Button" layoutX="211.0" layoutY="127.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnClicked" text="Button" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="247.4" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="211.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="337.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="127.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Code in Hello class:

```
package paczka.p2;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");
    }
}
```

Code in Controller class:

```
package paczka.p2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Error in console:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: No controller specified.
/D:/user_Folder/Projekty/P2/target/classes/paczka/p2/hello-view.fxml:9

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2703)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.getControllerMethodHandle(FXMLLoader.java:568)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:781)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2924)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2639)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at paczka.p2/paczka.p2.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application paczka.p2.HelloApplication

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You need an [`fx:conttoller`  element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers).

Comment: work through a tutorial on how to use fxml..

Comment: As well as the missing `fx:controller` attribute, your `onAction` attribute does not match the method name.

Comment: ok, right, I missed about that, but when i fix it, there is another problem. My console printing has such as problem: 
```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: D:\user_Folder\Projekty\P2\target\classes
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: HelloController.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)

Process finished with exit code 1
```
and I don't understand it

Answer (score 0):

Your issue starts in the `hello-view.fxml` file.
In your anchor pane, you need an `fx:controller` attribute.
It should look something like this:

```
fx:controller="HelloController" <!-- Assumes all folders in the same directory. -->
fx:controller="controller.HelloController" <!-- Assumes `HelloController.java` is located in `src > controller -->
```

Once you've set `hello-view.fxml` to properly look for `HelloController.java`, you want to visit your `button` element and set its `onAction` attribute to a function inside the controller.

Simply put, your Controller's function is `onHelloButtonClick()`, so the button's attribute should be:

```
onAction="#onHelloButtonClick()"
```

Now, as it currently stands, your controller's function sets a text element that doesn't exist in your `.fxml` file. You'd want to add this:

```
<Text fx:id="welcomeText"></Text>
```

Finally, `HelloController.java` needs a variable for each element you're interacting with. That means one for your button and one for your text.
Their names are decided by the `fx:id` attributes you set in `hello-View.fxml`

```
public Text welcomeText;
public Button Button;
```

In the end, this all comes together as follows:

Your Java program starts with the main function which, as you wrote, finds and reveals a `hello-view.fxml`. That `.fxml` file sets a `fx:controller="HelloController` attribute in its anchorpane, that specificies for all of its functions to come from `HelloController.java`.

Each element in `hello-view.fxml` has an `fx:id` attribute designating the name of a variable that must be listed in in `HelloController.java`.

Elements in `hello-view.fxml` need an `onAction` attribute, matched to the exact name of a function in the element's controller (as you specified with `fx:controller`).

From there, `HelloController.java` has a variable for each element its points to in the `.fxml` file that called it, and any function in the controller points to its variables, where java simply knows what to do from there.